# Полностью прозрачный statusBar в сочетании с кастомным navigationBar

Tags: android, android-xml, android-style

Мне нужно чтобы `statusBar` был полностью прозрачным (и поверх верстки), но так чтобы `navigationBar` НЕ был поверх верстки. Мне нужно задать это в стилях, а не в коде.

Когда я в стилях ставлю `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>`, то мой `statusBar`(!) (почемуто, а не только `navigationBar`) становится поверх верстки (и полностью прозрачным).
А когда я ставлю `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` - то `statusBar` становится поверх верстки, но полу-прозрачным (затемненным), а не полностью прозрачным.